# Train station distance from center equals N miles

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

I have a very very huge array of positive integer numbers which represent how far a certain train station is away from the center, for example:

```
  S = {10, 200, 1000, 1500, 2019, 2200}
```

Train station S[0] is 10 miles away from the center. S is **always** sorted in **ascending** order, at any point in time, also before the algorithm starts. Just simply always.

I want to find a function which checks if there exist two train station with a distance of exactly N miles.

For example:
N = 1300 would give me true because 1500 - 200 = 1300.

**First approach**

Iterate over S and check for each element if the distance to another element is N. This gives me two loops and I guess O(n^2). I don't want O(n^2) because the array can be so huge it needs better performance.

**Other approaches**

I did a lot of research but all I found was that O(n) is possible. I want to have this time complexity. My solution looks like this, but unfortunately it does not work out at all.

```
  int a[] = {10, 200, 1000, 1500, 2019, 2200};
  int size = 6;
  int left = 0;
  int right = size - 1;
  int x, y, distance, tempdis;
  int N = 1300;

  while(left < right)
  {
    x = a[left];
    y = a[right];
    tempdis = x - y;
    distance = tempdis < 0 ? tempdis*(-1) : tempdis;

    if(distance == N)
    {
       printf("found pair: %d %d\n", left, right);
       break;
    }
    if(distance > N)
      left++;

    if(distance < N)
      right--;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, it is. At any point in time. Ascending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve linear time (`O(n)`) by only incrementing two pointers, `i` and `j`. You want to find `i` and `j` such that `a[j] - a[i] == N`. The logic is simple:

- if `a[j] - a[i] < N`: increment `j` (distance gets larger)
- if `a[j] - a[i] > N`: increment `i` (distance gets smaller)

That's all! In code:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while ((a[j] - a[i] != N) && j < size) { // size is length of a
    if (a[j] - a[i] < N) {
        j++;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}

if (j < size) {
    printf("found pair: %d %d\n", i, j);
}
```

---

Handwaving proof of correctness: in principle, we should check each `a[j]` against all `a[i]` that could potentially give a solution. That is, for each `j`, we check a range `p_j <= i <= q_j`, such that `a[j] - a[p_j] > N` and `a[j] - a[q_j] < N`. If there is a solution involving `j`, it must be found in that range of `i` values.

Now, this algorithm almost does that, with one exception: sometimes we increment `j` multiple times in a row, so we clearly did not check it against a whole range. We increment `j` again, because `a[j] - a[i] < N`. However, if that happens, we also know that `a[j] - a[i-1] > N`. I leave it up to you to verify this.

This means that we check `j` against the range of all `i` values that can potentially give a solution. And thus the result is correct.

We have two pointers. In each step, one pointer is incremented. The size of the larger of the 2 (`j`) is bounded by `n`, so this runs in `O(n)` time.

Comment: But how is this different do my solution? Can you say anything about the time complexity?

Comment: @今天春天 your pointers are moving towards each other, whereas mine are following a sliding window approach. I don't see how to make the algorithm work with pointers moving towards each other.

Comment: @今天春天 it does not print anything if there is no solution. How is that not working? It cannot make up a solution.

Comment: Another issue: Maybe at the beginning i should be 0 and j should be 1, then we can save another comparison....because the first one will always lead into the case a[j] - a[i] < N.

Comment: Can you give me example data for a worst case scenario?

Comment: Of course, starting `j` at 1 saves one comparison but it doesn't influence the asymptotic complexity. A worst case would be an array without solution and the difference between the last two elements is `> N`, in which case it would take `2n-1` steps to find out there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

`sum` should be changed to `distance`
And it should be:

```
if(distance < N) {
  right--;
  left--;
}
```

Not just

```
if(distance < N)
  right--;
```

Comment: Is this O(n)? If yes, why?

Comment: Sure it's not. But it's faster than two loops.

Comment: Why is this not linear? What is the time complexity of this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in this block of code:

```
if (distance < N)
    right--;
```

You also want to decrement the value of `left` here:

```
if (distance < N)
{
    right--;
    left--;
}
```

Also, the variable `sum` in line:12 should be `distance`.

Comment: Is this O(n)? If yes, why?

Comment: It isn't. But in practical terms, it works better than using 2 loops.